# Probability inequality: $ \mathbb{P}(X\in A, X \ne Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y \in A, X \ne Y) \le \mathbb{P}(X \ne Y) $

Tags: probability, inequality

Given a joint probability distribution of $(X, Y)$ and for any event $A$, we have

$$ \mathbb{P}(X\in A, X \ne Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y \in A, X \ne Y) \le \mathbb{P}(X \ne Y) $$

I am struggling why this inequality holds.

What I've tried is $$ \mathbb{P}(X\in A, X \ne Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y \in A, X \ne Y) \le  \mathbb{P}(X\in A, X \ne Y) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A | X \ne Y)\mathbb{P}(X \ne Y) \le \mathbb{P}(X \ne Y)$$

I am not sure if this is correct and rigorous proof.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: It is much better to leave out the conditional probability. Inequality $\mathbb P(X\in A,X\neq Y)\leq\mathbb P(X\neq Y)$ is immediate.

Comment: Rigorously you will need to prove that $P(X \uneq Y)$ is non zero. Otherwise you cannot define the conditional probability.